# Emulate limited resource device android

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to find a NullPointerException that I get when in my app the phone release memory. I was testing on a Samsung G3, but now that I have change for a GS2 which has more RAM memory, the variable is still there when I minimaze/maximize.
Is there any way to simulate my old phone and his limited RAM memory? A bit ironic,but now I miss it...In the SDK emulators I can set SD card size, but not the RAM, which I guess is the key problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a program on the android market called CPU Master. You can set CPU speed so then you can test your program as in a phone with limited resources.